# WordPress sidebar shows up below content

Tags: wordpress, sidebar

I am running the latest wordpress version with a program called Zina. I turn an option on to display the sidebar on the Zina page, but instead of on the right it shows below the content. Any idea why this might be?

Here is the page: http://www.mixtapejerks.com/wordpress/?page_id=3

Thanks!

MJ

Answer (score 1):

I would reckon this is more of a CSS issue than anything else..
on your page the Zina div which encompasses the entire zina information is taken up the entire page,

you could add this to your style.css file

```
#zina { width:600px; float:left; }
#sidebar { 
   border-left:1px solid #CCCCCC;
   float:right;
   padding:10px;
   width:300px;
}
```

then once you load the page the sidebar should float to the right of the page and the left for the zina content? although you may have to mess about to get it just right..

ie: [image]

Answer (score 0):

I used to suffer this,

I think I got the answer originally that its long address' in links or too big an image. Images sizes are usually specified in theme_whatever.

These days with the latest versions we don't get such problems as we now use (when it works) the media file system where we have three different sizes.

Of course in the backend you can decide what size now.

HTH.